# How to link MSTest with Report Portal?

Tags: reportportal

We have a Coded UI solution in TFS and run tests from MS Test Manager. How can I post test results into Report Portal? 
I have just installed NUGet package from [github](https://github.com/reportportal/client-net)

But it is unclear for me how to use it. Is there some documentation about using of Report Portal API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, ReportPortal have no MSTest agent yet. But it has reach API so you could try to implement agent by yourself. 
There are couple of other .NET-based clients (as example):
[NUunit](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-net-nunit), [Specflow](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-net-specflow)

Server-side API is quite powerful to implement integration with any testing engine. You can have a look at it by the following link (must be logged in):
YOUR_RP_URL/ui/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Looks good!!! But it will be fine to get more description of each method.

Comment: It will be enough to get some end-to-end scenario (consequence of usage of API methods to log whole test run).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there now there is something that can connect reportportal and mstest: https://github.com/reportportal/agent-net-vstest